# Seekbar customize without repetition

Tags: android, seekbar, customization

I have the Seekbar that I customized but the background is going to do the repetition and I want to remove it.

This is my file where I am going to customize the SeekBar:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
android:drawable="@drawable/slider_background">

</item>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: Yes, how to remove the repetition!

Comment: I think he means the @drawable/slider_background repeats like a pattern.  I ran into the same issue a while back and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: The only solution that I found is that I created the image in the right size.
Yes I can use the nine patch but I had a problem with a border around the image.

Answer (score 0):

In order to strech your bitmap, and avoid the repetition, you must transform your image into a 9-patch. Follow the guide below to create your .9.png file from your image :

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Then, you must reference it as a nine-patch in your xml file :

```
  <item android:id="@android:id/background">
      <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/seekbar_background"></nine-patch>
  </item>
```

As this answers your question and can help other people, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer.